# JSF, Exception Logging using a aopalliance MethodInterceptor

Tags: jsf, exception, aop, guice, aopalliance

I would like to log the exceptions that are thrown when serving JSF files in the same way other exceptions are logged in our web application.

We annotate classes with logged exceptions with `@LoggedExceptions` and a `MehtodInterceptor` is matched against those classes with Guice AOP (This should be very similar for other implementations of aopalliance...)

The main problem is, that the method interceptor does not work. How can i intercept method calls on JSF-backing code?

Answer (score 0):

You must replace the default el-resolver (`<el-resolver>` in `faces-context.xml`) with a Guice el-resolver, so that the jsf beans become instantiated by Guide.

Search for "Guice el resolver", or take [this one](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/7171) (I can't guarantee it works). Also check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971807/guice-and-jsf-2).

Also, [read the top results of this google search](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=jsf+guice+integration&sourceid=navclient-ff&rlz=1B3GGGL_enBG314BG344&ie=UTF-8&aq=0&oq=jsf+guice+)

Comment: I already have a `VariableResolver`:
http://snipplr.com/view/26748/guice-variable-resolver/

This is bound with the following code in faces-config.xml:
`<variable-resolver>a.b.c.GuiceVariableResolver</variable-resolver>`

Comment: at least in my config using spring, it is the <el-resolver>, not <variable-resolver>

Comment: Ill try getting a custom el-resolver in there and report back.

Comment: how do you know it's silently ignored?

Comment: and it doesn't matter icefaces or not